# Unable to activate a PIM role

Tags: azure-active-directory

Stackoverflow

I tried to activate a role assignment in powershell. Basically trying to create a script to just run all my roles in single click - and not that I need to get to AzureAD and click every role and activate them. (and wait for activation...).

So basically I tried this:

```
$schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule 
$schedule.Type = "Once"
#Schedule starts from now
$schedule.StartDateTime =(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
#Schedule ends after 4 hours 
$schedule.endDateTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(0.5).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ") 
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId 'aadRoles'
-ResourceId '<My Resource ID>' -RoleDefinitionId 'fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1' -SubjectId 'af25fdae-dc28-4855-b22d-4f5881b89ea9' -AssignmentState 'Active' -Type 'userAdd' -Schedule $schedule -Reason "Work"
```

The error I receive:

```
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest : Error occurred while executing
OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
Code: InvalidScope
Message: The resource scope is not valid.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 766f029f-0be6-420b-b961-f56ce8736bd6
  DateTimeStamp: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 06:36:21 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:10 char:1
+ Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId 'aadRoles'  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Open-AzureADMSP...signmentRequest], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
```

When I try to change -Type "userAdd" for -Type "adminAdd" the error is different:

```
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest : Error occurred while executing
OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
Code: RoleAssignmentRequestPolicyValidationFailed
Message: The following policy rules failed: ["AdminRequestRule"]
InnerError:
  RequestId: f180bba3-d557-491f-b4be-525b8a0d6483
  DateTimeStamp: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 06:55:01 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:7 char:1
+ Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId 'aadRoles'  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Open-AzureADMSP...signmentRequest], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
```

I am actually unable to find the solution. Maybe some settings of the role? I try also change -AssigmentState for "Eligible" but it doesn't change much.

Comment: 'addRoles' does not need single quotes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/open-azureadmsprivilegedroleassignmentrequest?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#example-1-create-an-eligible-role-assignment-request

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, please try making use of the below PowerShell script:

```bash
$role = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId "TenantId" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}

$schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule
$schedule.Type = "Once"
$schedule.StartDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
$schedule.endDateTime = "2022-10-21T20:49:11.770Z"

Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId aadRoles -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId "TenantId" -RoleDefinitionId $role.Id -SubjectId "UserObjectId" -AssignmentState "Eligible" -Type "AdminAdd"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error seems different than yours - same as the scope of the role I try to activate.
Mine is Administrative Unit - not Directory. I think this might be the case why it is not activate as it should. Other roles that are not "Directory" are normally activating...

Comment: Also, @rukmini based on your script:

$schedule.endDateTime = "2022-10-21T20:49:11.770Z" - this line is not working for me (only duration of hours like I have) - error I receive is ["expirationRule"]

Answer (score 0):

because I'm running into the exact same problem, I've found your post through the search.
Currently, I believe, the AzureAD preview module simply doesn't support activating eligible but scoped assignments.

Here's what I found on the web:

https://danielchronlund.com/2021/09/17/activate-your-azure-ad-pim-roles-with-powershell/#comment-3726
and
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/16476

The latter is a feature request, and it's about creating a scoped assignment, not activating it, but I fear the effect is the same: scoped assignments are not supported (yet).
The bleak answer given is that one should post that request to MS Support.

--
Cheers,
pk

Comment: btw, I tried using the `ResourceId` parameter with the ID of the Administrative Unit that my role assignment was scoped to (instead of the directory ID), but that didn't help. The error then turned to 
`Code: RoleNotFound
Message: The role is not found.`

Comment: I think it is good idea to create a ticket to MS Support, but anyway I also think it is dead end

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. I tried it just now and it works:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/tutorial-pim?view=graph-powershell-1.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004796

However, I can't figure out how to activate PIM roles for Azure resources.