# Activate PIM role for Azure resources via REST / Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to automate the activation of my PIM role for Azure resources via Powershell or REST API and I can't seem to figure this out. I can activate PIM role for AAD just fine, but not Azure resources. Does anyone how an example of this working?

I found this and tried it, but it doesn't work for activating PIM role configured at the management group level for some reason. Works fine for PIM roles on the subscription level.

[Unable to activate a PIM role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149941/unable-to-activate-a-pim-role)

For AAD role activation, this is what I used:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/tutorial-pim?view=graph-powershell-1.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004796

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you using an Admin like 1st link?  Notice in 1st link error message changed when using an Admin.

Answer (score 1):

To **activate** PIM role for Azure resources under management group via *REST API*, you can make use of below call:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mgname/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignmentScheduleRequests/<new_guid>?api-version=2020-10-01

 {
  "properties": {
    "principalId": "userObjId",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mgname/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635",
    "requestType": "SelfActivate",
    "justification": "test purpose",
    "scheduleInfo": {
      "startDateTime": "2023-10-09T18:11:53.8442481+05:30",
      "expiration": {
        "type": "AfterDuration",
        "endDateTime": null,
        "duration": "PT1H"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, PIM role **activated** successfully under management group like this:

[image]

To **activate** PIM role for Azure resources under management group via *PowerShell*, you can make use of below script:

```
$guid = "fcffe158-978e-4125-be75-xxxxx" 
$startTime = Get-Date -Format o 
$scope = "//providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/mgname/"
$principalID = "userObjId"
$roledefinitionid = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Samplegroup1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"

New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest -Name $guid -Scope $scope -ExpirationDuration PT1H -ExpirationType AfterDuration -PrincipalId $principalID -RequestType SelfActivate -RoleDefinitionId $roledefinitionID -ScheduleInfoStartDateTime $startTime -Justification "demo purpose"
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[Activate Azure resource roles in PIM - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-activate-your-roles#activate-a-role-with-arm-api)

[Enable role fails with permission error (github.com) by **chaoscreater**](https://github.com/JustinGrote/JAz.PIM/issues/10#issuecomment-1752005317)

Comment: If the status of the returned request object's status field is PendingApprovalProvisioning and the you pim configuration isn't requiring approval, you can trigger a self-approved approval by including -LinkedRoleEligibilityScheduleId. Upon success, the status field should now be returned as Provisioned